# ApplicationSettingsBase does not save nested object

Tags: c#, wpf, application-settings

I have this settings class

```
class AppSettings : ApplicationSettingsBase
{
    [UserScopedSettingAttribute()]        
    public ObservableCollection<TrackViewModel> TracksViewModel
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<TrackViewModel>)(this["TracksViewModel"]); }
        set { this["TracksViewModel"] = value; }
    }
```

...

TracksViewModel has a property Track (my Model), which is a class.
Also this class has a empty constructor, so I guess this make no problem.

Anyway, when I save Settings, all the Properties are saved but Track object.
In output debug I got no errors.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

How does the appsettings know they type of the ViewModel? You may want to check the serialization of that object.

Or, you many want to not use appsettings for this and roll your own xml file for persisting that stuff.

Here are several links:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6730/Custom-Objects-From-the-App-Config-file

[How to store class object in app config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387444/how-to-store-class-object-in-app-config-file)

[Can I save an object to the app.config file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382783/can-i-save-an-object-to-the-app-config-file)

[How to Read Custom XML from the app.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148611/how-to-read-custom-xml-from-the-app-config)

[How to serialize collections in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639303/how-to-serialize-collections-in-net)

Comment: I wish to prefer to continue using ApplicationSettingsBase

Sorry, how could I solve this ?

I tried to put 
[Serializable()] up to Track object, but nothing happens

Comment: Now that you have marked your class as serializable, have you implemented the process of serialization?

Comment: Do you mean implementing ISerializable?
No I didn't... Honestly I don't know much about the process.
I'm trying to read something about this.
Do you know some useful sources ? Thank you very much
(Sorry but I've no enough reputation to mark your answer useful)

Comment: @user1649247 I've added some links in my answer.